# What is the difference between Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory vs HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory

Tags: java, spring, performance, nio, resttemplate

What is the difference between [`Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory.html) and [`HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory.html)? I am planning to use [`AsyncRestTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/AsyncRestTemplate.html) in one of my project so not sure which request factory we should use and how do we decide?

```
private final AsyncRestTemplate asyncRestTemplate = new AsyncRestTemplate(new HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory());

private final AsyncRestTemplate asyncRestTemplate = new AsyncRestTemplate(new Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory ());
```

I guess internal behaviour of `AsyncRestTemplate` will depend on how we create the object so wanted to make sure I understand this correctly.

The only difference I can see is `Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory` uses `Netty 4` to create requests and `HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory` uses `Apache HttpComponents HttpAsyncClient 4.0` to create requests and I  don't know what does this mean underhood? And which one is better and how to decide which one to use and when?

Comment: Have you read the documentatio of both classes?

Comment: @Jens Yeah I tried it but not able to understand fully. I am not still not in the league where I can understand stuff from Java Docs so still in the  learning phase.

Comment: The only difference I can see that is Netty4 vs HttpAsyncClient4 and I  don't know which one does what underhood and which one is better.